# How to fix Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server

I tried a lot but can't find what is wrong with this query, It gave me this error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(See) AS [All]
 , (
       SELECT TOP 1 See
       FROM StateSite
       WHERE StatDate = @StatDate
   ) AS [Now]
 , (
       SELECT TOP 1 See
       FROM StateSite
       WHERE StatDate = @Yesterday
   ) AS [Last]
 , (
       SELECT SUM(See)
       FROM (
           SELECT TOP 7 *
           FROM StateSite
           ORDER BY id DESC
       )
   ) AS [week]
FROM StateSite";
```

also that works properly with access database but not by sql server.

Comment: Rewrite it to readable multiline query and you will see the problem yourself.

Comment: Have you  tried `))as[week]` to `) as d) as [week]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is you are trying to select from a subquery without assigning an alias to the result set.

All you have to do is change your query from this

```
string query = "select sum(See) as[All] ,(select top 1 See from StateSite
where StatDate=@StatDate)as[Now], (select top 1 See from StateSite where
StatDate=@Yesterday)as[Last],(select sum(See)  from  (select top 7 * from
StateSite order by ID desc))as[week] From StateSite";
```

To this

```
string query = "select sum(See) as[All] ,(select top 1 See from StateSite
where StatDate=@StatDate)as[Now], (select top 1 See from StateSite where
StatDate=@Yesterday)as[Last],(select sum(See)  from  (select top 7 * from
StateSite order by ID desc) as [subQuery])as[week] From StateSite";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    [All] = SUM(See),
    [Now] = MAX(CASE WHEN StatDate = @StatDate THEN See END),
    [Last] = MAX(CASE WHEN StatDate = @Yesterday THEN See END),
    [week] = SUM(CASE WHEN RowNum < 8 THEN See END)
FROM (
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC)
    FROM StateSite
) t
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not desired in SO, it would be better to include some text to explain what was wrong.

Comment: @Bahareh Feizi , np... but in future check about re-read from the same table ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to directly run your query to database and check if syntax is correct. There can be multiple () where your query might be failing. For example in my case the argument passed for IN clause was empty creating my query something like `select * from tableName where id in ()` and hence was getting error.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDistinctDescriptionsAndUnits()
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT DESCRIPTION, UNIT
    FROM keyfood
    WHERE (
            description LIKE '% % [0-9]%oz%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% lb%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% ml%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% ltr%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% fl oz%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% cans%'
            OR description LIKE '% [0-9] L%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% floz%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% liter%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% gal%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]-%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]%-gal%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]%-ct.%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]%.% Gallon%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]% LBS%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]%-lbs%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9]%.% oz.%'
            OR description LIKE '% % [0-9].[0-9]% fl. oz.%'
        )
        AND (unit IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(unit)) = '');
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**